# Callback functions not properly executing in Action Creator

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm creating a dashboard that needs to pull elements from multiple separate parts of a SQL database in order to create a useable store for the application. The calls need to be performed sequentially, as they rely on data from the previous call to act as an argument in subsequent calls (EXAMPLE: a username and password are inserted initially, this allows us to locate a user ID in the database which we can then use to locate the targets that are available for them to see, which we can then use to grab the actual data about each target)

I'm new to Redux (and to chaining together async promises like this). I've been thinking that the best way to accomplish this is to chain together the different promises in an action creator. However, I'm getting some behavior I can't fully explain.

The action creator is below:

```
export function setReduxStore(username, password) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return dispatch(
      loginUser(username, password)
      ).then((customerId) =>
      setAvailableTargets(customerId)
      )
  }
}
```

As you can see the action creator first fires 'loginUser()'. This part triggers correctly. The code for login user can be found below:

```
export function loginUser(username, password) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost:3050/users/login',
      data: {
        username: username,
        password: password
      }
    }).then((response) => {
      dispatch({type: "LOGIN_USER", payload: response})
      return response.data.data[0].customer_id
    })
  }
}
```

However, in the 'setReduxStore()' action creator I then have it setup to trigger a second query to help set the available targets. This call accepts an ID returned from the user login as an argument. The code for this action is below:

```
export function setAvailableTargets(customer_id) {
  return function (dispatch) {
  console.log("set targets fired with customer Id " + customer_id)
  return axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:3050/users/targets/' + customer_id,
    data: {
      customer_id: customer_id
    }
  }).then((response) => {
    dispatch({type: 'SET_AVAILABLE_TARGETS', payload: response})
    return response.data.data[0].id
  })
  }
}
```

You'll notice that I have a console log statement within that function - when I put it above

```
return function (dispatch)
```

It will fire with the appropriate ID provided from loginUser. However, nothing below the 'return function (dispatch)' is firing. If I call the method outside the promise chain it works, so there's something about the way it's being called within the action creator that is triggering the function but not actually allowing it to execute any of its meaningful pieces of code.

Not sure if it matters, but once this is figured out I need to build out the promise chain more - and fetch the actual data based on the ID(s) returned from setAvailableTargets().

EDIT: For anyone with a similar problem, the answer below helped lead me to a functioning sequence that looks like this:

```
  export function setReduxStore(username, password) {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    return dispatch(
      loginUser(username, password)
      ).then(() => {
        return dispatch (
        setAvailableTargets(getState().currentUser.customerId)
        )
      })
  }
}
```

I had a function firing, but it wasn't dispatching which was preventing it from running any of the meaningful code. I had to make sure to return a new dispatch at each concrete stage of the bundled function.

Comment: There's no reason for you to return the promises if all you're doing is waiting for them to resolve and dispatching further actions. It's also an anti pattern to return values from a redux action creator. Instead, connect your component to receive the new state as your store updates. Try removing the return statements preceding your axios calls.

Comment: When I do that I receive the following error: "Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions."

Comment: are you using thunk middleware for redux?

Comment: Yes I'm using thunk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from the comments above, you need to return plain objects from actions. Since you're using redux thunk middleware, you can return functions as actions.

```
export function setReduxStore(username, password) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    loginUser(username, password)
      .then((customerId) =>
        dispatch(setAvailableTargets(customerId))
      )
  }
}

export function loginUser(username, password) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost:3050/users/login',
      data: {
        username: username,
        password: password
      }
    }).then((response) => {
      dispatch({type: "LOGIN_USER", payload: response})
      //return response.data.data[0].customer_id
      // Get data from store instead
    })
  }
}

export function setAvailableTargets(customer_id) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    console.log("set targets fired with customer Id " + customer_id)
    axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://localhost:3050/users/targets/' + customer_id,
      data: {
        customer_id: customer_id
      }
    }).then((response) => {
      dispatch({type: 'SET_AVAILABLE_TARGETS', payload: response})
      //return response.data.data[0].id
      // Get data from store instead
    })
  }
}
```

A common pattern with async actions in redux is to define 'request', 'success', 'failure' action types so that your UI knows whether to render a loading animation, error message, or response data.

see: http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html

Comment: Thank you! I had been beating my head against this code so long I wasn't considering some obvious things. Just seeing your example made it obvious that I had some bits of code that were doing nothing and I needed to restructure what exactly was getting called.